# call dynamic data with ng-option in dropdownlist angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-options

```
<select ng-option="ubrandname as ubrandname.brand for brand in ubrandname track by ubrandname.brand" ng-model="ubrandname"></select>
```

this is my dropdownlist for calling dynamic set of data from my `js` file

```
//brandnamebyid
            $http.get('/brandinfo.asmx/getbrandname', {
                params: {
                    log: log,
                    pm: pm,
                    id: $scope.updateparam.Id
                }
            })

            .then(function (response) {
                {
                    $scope.brandfunction = response.data.branddetails;
                    $scope.ubrandname = $scope.brandfunction[0];
                    console.log($scope.ubrandname);
                }
            });
```

i think i am unable to write correct syntax of ng-option in my dropdownlist, can anyone help me out here?

Answer (score 0):

Your ng-model and ng-option data source seems same. Please try as below,

```
<select ng-option="brand as brand.brand for brand in brandfunction track by $index" ng-model="ubrandname"></select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
<select ng-model="ubrandname">
    <option ng-repeat="brandname in brandfunction" value="{{brandname}}">{{brandname}}</option>
</select>
```